# IRepository Pattern - Interface Segregation Principle

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, interface, repository

I have an `IRepository` class that I use a lot.  But I noticed that for many of my repositories I do not implement most of the methods.  Also,  I usually don't have a `TKey` that I want to specify if I'm not using the `GetById` method but the current design forces me to specify it.  I was thinking of changing the interface or splitting up the interface into multiple smaller interfaces in order to make it cleaner and easier to use. Any ideas?

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey>
{
    TEntity Insert(TEntity entity);

    TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    TEntity GetById(TKey key);

    TEntity Update(TEntity entity);

    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

Here is an example implementation. Let me know if you need to see more than one method.  It is somewhat self explanatory.

```
/// <summary>
/// The invoices repository.
/// </summary>
public class InvoicesRepository : IRepository<Invoice, int>
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public InvoicesRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public Invoice Insert(Invoice entity)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO INVOICES VALUES (entity.SomeProp)", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            entity.Id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            return entity;
        }
    }

    public Invoice Find(Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> predicate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public IQueryable<Invoice> FindAll(Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> predicate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Invoice GetById(int key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Invoice Update(Invoice entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<Invoice> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(Invoice entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Invoice GetById(int key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a better CR post if you included a few implementations for that interface, IMO.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Added simple example to show Insert method.  Let me know if you would like to see more.

Comment: This `InvoiceRepository` is real? Or made-up? The point I'm trying to make is that [hypothetical/example code is frowned upon](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/23788), we like having as much context as possible - don't be afraid to include "too much code", this isn't Stack Overflow where you have to keep it short & sweet - on Code Review if you narrow it down too much, it gets hard to... review ;) For instance, who is the calling code for such a repository? Does that `IQueryable` ends up in the UI layer?

Comment: @Mat'sMug It is made up.  The original question was about interface design.  You asked for example code to maybe get a clearer understanding of what the interface was doing and I tried to give that without giving any of my internal repos away (DTOs, tables, etc).  But to answer your questions,  anything can use the repos.  Could be the service/business layer.  I have sometimes used these `IRepository`s directly in an `ApiController` constructor and use them as CRUD methods mapping to `Get`, `Put`, `Post`, `Delete`.

Comment: Personally I am not a fan of this style. I would prefer to have an IInvoicesRepository that you can then use for injection where necessary. That allows you to specify only the methods you need. I don't see a huge benefit in the generic interface over a specific interface for the class.

Comment: @SteveMichael So if I have like 30 entities, I will need 30 interfaces?  That seems like a lot of extra work, right?  I'm trying to reduce the work needed. That is why I'm trying to break up the interface into smaller interfaces that I can then use in some abstract classes that implement a couple commonly used interfaces or a common interface for my solution.  Makes sense?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I honestly don't think it's that much work. Creating interfaces is very quick. The benefit is that each interface has exactly what it needs. No more no less. If you follow your path you will need to create IInsertRepository, IFindRepository, etc. That seems like a poor solution to me. Feels like over engineering. Again the benefit of abstract repositories there doesn't feel like a huge gain to me. I prefer to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

The ISP is indeed taking a beating with all these `NotImplementedException`. If we boil this interface a little (ok a lot), we get this:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    TEntity Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
}
```

These two should always be implemented, assuming all entity types can at least be *selected*. I haven't included `GetById` because it makes things more complicated, and it's really `Find` all over again (especially when you have an entity with a composite PK).

That said, `TEntity Find(...)` feels a bit awkward: one could expect a "Find" method to return more than a single result, like `FindAll` does. I think it's the naming that's off: `Find` should be `Single`, or perhaps `Select` (consistent with the LINQ method that does the same thing), and then `FindAll` could become `Find`.

`IQueryable<TEntity>` shouldn't be permitted to exist beyond the data access layer - there's no reason `FindAll` can't *materialize* the query itself and return an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` instead, making sure that any further LINQ code on the client side doesn't get to the database.

I'd make `Find` return an `IEnumerable<TEntity>`.

---

Now to keep the ISP happy, we'd have an `IInsertable<TEntity>`, an `IUpdatable<TEntity>` and an `IDeletable<TEntity>`, respectively with `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete` methods; a repository that supports updates will implement `IUpdatable<TEntity>`, and a repository that doesn't support deletions won't implement `IDeletable<TEntity>`.

I don't think it's ideal, but it strips the repository interface down quite a bit - in fact it could even be renamed `ISelectable<TEntity>` at this point. An `ApiController` would use an `IInsertable<Invoice>` to insert an invoice in a method, and an `IDeletable<Invoice>` to delete that invoice in another method - and both methods would actually be dealing with an `InvoiceRepository`.

Comment: The part about not permitting use of methods was unclear to me though. I can't control who uses the interface. But if you mean to not use `IQueryable` then I think I understand. I have always been on the fence about that. For lazy loading it is great. For anything else I would use `IEnumerable`. But maybe I should rethink it. Any guidance on that?

Comment: I only ever included `TKey` because of the possibility of strange / composite keys.  Your answer is incredibly interesting.  I think it should work with all use cases. I will play around with it.  Maybe post some gists.

Comment: The client code has no way of knowing whether the `IQueryable` will operate against LINQ-to-Objects, or if it needs to bear in mind that it's LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities and that the supplied `Expression` parameters must account for that. If you expose an `IEnumerable` instead, the client code can rightfully expect and assume LINQ-to-Objects and a materialized query. It's all just for clarity :)